# Not able to switch my Docker's automatic build repository to a private repository for an Organisation

Tags: repository, docker, private, namespace-organisation

when I try to switch my automatic build repository to a private one, I got a message telling me that I must upgrade my plan. I'm a-on a free plan (only 1 private repository).
The fact is I had a previous repository in the private section and I removed it. After that I got the message "(used 0 of 1)". So all seems correct at this point.
My namespace is "org4svcorp" which is an Organisation.

Even If I try to add a repository (not an automatic build) with the organisation in namespace field I have the message:
"Maximum number of repositories reached

This organization has reached the maximum number of repositories allowed. Please have one of the organization owners upgrade the plan on the organization billing page."

Once again the status for the private repositories is : "(used 0 of 1)"

Is there a restriction with the organisations?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Organizations do not get any free private repositories. You'll need to pay for a subscription on your organization.

The subscription page for an organization is a bit hard to find -- we're working on an improved workflow. I've added some stopgap docs here: https://forums.docker.com/t/adding-private-repos-to-an-organization/317?u=rufus